# In Python: When does a function use a certain stored memory block?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, function, memory

I'm a beginner in Python. If you run the following simple code:

```
def f(x,l=[]):
    for i in range(x):
        l.append(i*i)
    print(l)
f(2)
f(3,[3,2,1])
f(3)
```

The output is:

```
[0, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 4]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 4]
```

The third output doesn't make sense to me. I found an explanation [here](https://www.codementor.io/sheena/essential-python-interview-questions-du107ozr6), but again not clear. I mean if the list stores the previous value in memory `[0, 1]`, why then not store `[3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 4]`? According to the explanation mentioned above, the function "uses the ***original*** list stored in the original memory block". But we have two `[0, 1]`, and `[3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 4]`.

How can I say which one is the ***original***?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument?s=1|784.4155

Comment: on the second call you're not using the default argument, so it's only stored in call 1 and 3.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks for the comment. But can I overcome this thing? I mean if I want to call such function without using the previous value. I read that one may use None, I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: it means use None as default argument, and if it's None, create a list in the function so it's independent from other calls. never use a mutable default value.